# how to get same village in multiple accounts in coc!

Tags: clash-of-clans

Is there any way I can use my village and its progress on another account of mine and still be able to use both. Its too hard to start from the beginning.

Comment: Click Transfer Device in the settings button in the game

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try to first disconnect your acount then directly connect it